# Making custom Yesod Form: Could not deduce (Monad (FormInput m))

Tags: forms, haskell, monads, yesod

I am trying to make multi-file form input. I am using [Handling a collection of data in a Yesod Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182020/handling-a-collection-of-data-in-a-yesod-form) as a reference.

Here I am trying to make association list of field names to files.

```
multiFileInput :: Monad m => RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage =>
                  [Text] -> FormInput m [(Text, FileInfo)]
multiFileInput = mapM $ secondM (ireq fileField) . (getFieldKey &&& id)
```

I get error:

```
Could not deduce (Monad (FormInput m))
    arising from a use of ‘mapM’
```

But I don't know how to handle this. If I just add this as a constraint I have to propagade this constraint "(Monad (FormInput Handler))" up to a call site, where I don't know how to handle it. FormInput m is an instance of Monad, so I don't understand the issue.

```
fileInfos <- runInputPost $ multiKeyFileInput "files"

-> No instance for (Monad (FormInput Handler))
    arising from a use of ‘multiKeyFileInput’
```

I will try to use runRequestBody instead, but it would be nice to understand the problem.

Comment: What if you change `mapM` to `traverse`?

Comment: @arrowd That worked, thank you! I forgot that traverse is an applicative version of mapM, so that it's less of a constraint on a target type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FormInput` data type was supposedly changed from `Monad` to `Applicative`, so you have to use `traverse`, which is an `Applicative` version of `mapM`.